# How to undo hairline remove in Swift for different pages?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

I am developing an app in which the home page of the app has a white navigation bar with the hairline hidden, and the remaining pages having a green nav bar. What I've done so far is put the code for the home page nav bar in its own .swift file, but what happens is that when I navigate to my other pages through the buttons on the home page (as opposed to the menu bar) the navigation bar's still set to white. I think it's because the code that removes the hairline carries through to other pages when accessed through the buttons.

This is what my page should ideally look like:
[Homepage & Module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPMxd.jpg)

Instead this is what the module page looks like: [Module Page Now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92Qoi.png)

This is the code I'm using - wondering if anyone can help me figure out how to reverse the code or if there's an alternate solution.

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    // Set navigation bar tint / background colour
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    // Set Navigation bar Title colour
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.blackColor()]

    //Set navigation bar Back button tint colour
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()

    //Get Rid of 1px hairline
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(
        UIImage(),
        forBarPosition: .Any,
        barMetrics: .Default)

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()

}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    // Set navigation bar tint / background colour
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 127/255, blue: 106/255, alpha: 1)

    // Set Navigation bar Title colour
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.whiteColor()]

    //Set navigation bar Back button tint colour
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    //Reverse get Rid of 1px hairline code
    /*self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(
        UIImage(),
        forBarPosition: .Any,
        barMetrics: .Default)

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()*/
}
```

Comment: What do you mean for "hairline"?

Comment: @AlessandroOrnano The 1px line that borders the bottom of the navigation bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to solve this by just reversing the code in the viewWillDisappear method.

```
  //Reverse get Rid of 1px hairline code
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(nil, forBarMetrics: .Default)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a custom swift file with general methods (called for example Utils.swift) and insert your function, then call it in the next controllers:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

//MARK: - General methods:
     func customizeNavigationController(navigationController:UINavigationController) {
          navigationController.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
          navigationController.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
          navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.greenColor()
          navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
          navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Black
          navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = false
          navigationController.navigationBar.clipsToBounds = false
          navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = nil
          self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
      }

      func changeNavHairLines(navigationController:UINavigationController, show:Bool) {
           for subview in navigationController.navigationBar.subviews {
               for view in subview.subviews {
                   if(view.frame.size.height < 4) {
                      if show == true { 
                          view.alpha = 1.0
                      } else {
                          view.alpha = 0.0
                      }
                   }
                }
           }
        }
```

To call it use:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    // choose if you want to show or hide hairLines
    changeNavHairLines(self.navigationController!,show:false)
    customizeNavigationController(self.navigationController!)
}
```

Comment: Hmm I'm happy to keep the border hairline on other pages aside from the homepage though. How do I get rid of the background image/shadow image on other pages if the code to set the background is already triggered when the home page is loaded? Sorry if this doesn't make sense.

Comment: Ok look now, I've added a function to remove this strange line

Answer (score 0):

1. To remove the thin black line ... In the `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear` of the relevant View where you want to remove the thin black line:

   //Remove thin black line at bottom of nav bar.

   > ```
   >     for parent in self.navigationController!.navigationBar.subviews {
   >         for childView in parent.subviews {
   >             if(childView is UIImageView) {
   >                 childView.removeFromSuperview()
   >             }
   >         }
   >     }
   > ```
2. Regarding different Nav Bar appearances and their color and related properties, etc. why not just customise each View's nav bar properties as you have done for your 'Home Page'?

Comment: I tried that but the "//Get Rid of 1px hairline" code carries through to other pages if navigated through the home page buttons - causing the nav bar to still be white/transparent. I don't know how to undo this code??

Answer (score 0):

The navigationBar in a navigationController is shared throughout the whole App, so removing it in one controller removes it for the whole App. How about hiding the navigationBar in the controller where you want to remove the hairline and placing a navigationBar manually via Interface Builder?

You can hide the navigationBar, when returning to the main view with:

```
self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
```

Place this in `viewWillAppear`.

And then show it again:

```
self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
```

In the `viewWillDisappear`.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I tried to do. What happens now is that when accessed through menu bar, my Modules page navigationBar shows up fine. But when accessed through the button on the HomePage, the navigation is still hidden... I think I need to undo the hiding bit through viewWillDisappear but I don't know how.